# State of intent extras when launching new Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have a main activity A and a different activity B, i perform an operation on B and return an arrayList in the extras to main activity A..I then launch a Filepicker intent on A. By launching the Filepicker intent, does the arraylist extra because null?

anotherRow is the ArrayList.

Activity B

```
 val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putSerializable(Constants.sendAdditionalRowsBack, anotherRow)
    intent.putExtras(bundle)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
```

MainActivity

```
val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
    //The below will be done only if bundle is not null
    if (bundle != null) {
        returnedArray = bundle?.getSerializable(Constants.sendAdditionalRowsBack) as ArrayList<bring>
    }else{
        runOnUiThread {
            activity?.makeLongToast("Bundle is null")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you proviede some code on how you are returning array list in extras?

Comment: to return data to `MainActivity` you should launch `ActivityB` using `startActivityForResult()` and process the reponse in `MainActivity.onActivityResult()`. This doesn't answer your question, it is just an observation.

Comment: When `MainActivity` launches `ActivityB`, does it finish? Is  `MainActivity` declared with `launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest? How are you launching the file picker?

Answer (score 0):

This is w hat eventually worked

Activity B (Sending)

```
 // intialize Bundle instance
    val b = Bundle()
    b.putSerializable("questions", anotherRow as Serializable?)
    val i = Intent(this, OneMainActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtras(b)
    startActivity(i)
    finish()
```

Activity A (Receiving)

```
    //get the bundle
    if (activity?.getIntent()?.extras != null) {
        val b = activity?.getIntent()?.extras
        if (b?.getSerializable("questions") as ArrayList<bring> != null) {
            returnedArray = (b!!.getSerializable("questions") as ArrayList<bring>?)!!
        } else {
            runOnUiThread {
                activity?.makeLongToast("An error occured")
            }
        }
    } else {
        runOnUiThread {
            //activity?.makeLongToast("An internal error occured")
        }
    }
```